# Mysql stored function freezing

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have a stored function in MySQL and it works partially.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getsubdomain`$$
CREATE FUNCTION getsubdomain(page_id int(11))
RETURNS CHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
declare current_p_id int(11);
declare current_p_parent_id int(11);
declare current_p_address_type char(255);
declare current_p_adress char(255);
SET current_p_id = page_id;
WHILE (current_p_id) <> 0
DO
select p_parent_id, p_address_type, p_adress from opu_pages where p_id = current_p_id into current_p_parent_id, current_p_address_type, current_p_adress;
IF current_p_address_type <> ''
THEN
IF current_p_address_type = 'subdomain'
THEN
RETURN current_p_adress;
ELSE
SET current_p_id = current_p_parent_id;
END IF;
ELSE
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END WHILE;
RETURN NULL;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I call in query `SELECT getsubdomain(p_id) FROM opu_pages;` it works Ok. But if I call it in `SELECT * FROM opu_pages WHERE getsubdomain(p_id)='library';` the database is collapsed and freezing.
Query and function work with one table.
What did I do wrong?
I thought that it can be caused by the table format MyISAM. But I can't change it to InnoDB because I use FULLTEXTFORMAT fields in this table.

Table `opu_pages` (MyISAM) scheme

```
p_id INT
p_parent_id INT
p_address_type ENUM (path, subdomain)
p_adress VARCHAR
```

Comment: Problem was in time. Query want more time for execute

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post I would say that your code is entering an infinite loop for some of your input parameters.

In particular the case where `p_id = p_parent_id` in the `opu_pages` table and the `current_p_address_type = 'subdomain'`

Comment: It works recursive. But when I call function like SELECT getsubdomain(p_id) FROM opu_pages; It works pretty and fast